# How to getting data by size with hasMap

Tags: java, android

the data generated from the hasmap is 200 data per second but I only want to save 50 data per second to firebase. I've tried using the if statement but it doesn't work. how to solve this problem. here's the code I use

```
Map<String,Object> rightDataDict = new HashMap<>();

                        Date date = new Date();
                    rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Do something after 100ms
                                if (rightDataDict.size() == 50) {
                                    sendToFirebase(rightDataPack, "Right_Insole");
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map `rightDataDict` should be declared outside the scope.

For example

```
public void addHandler(Map<String, Object map, Object pack) {
    map.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 100ms
            if (map.size() % 50 == 0) {
                sendToFirebase(pack, "Right_Insole");
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then in your code when the map is initialized you have

```
Map<String, Object> rightDataDict = new HashMap<>();
addHandler(rightDataDict, rightDataPack);
// handle logic to add values to map from here
```

Two things to keep in mind here

1. Thread safety if the map is accessed by different threads
2. What happens after the map has 50 entries? Should it be cleared by the handler?